# How allow multiple of one type of thread to run before another using semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading

Two mountain resorts are connected by a road that becomes single lane inside a tunnel that goes through the mountain. One resort is at the left end of the tunnel and the other at the right end of the tunnel. Cars moving from left to right are called “Right-bound” cars and are indicated with odd numbers starting from 1 (1, 3, 5, ...). “Left-bound” cars move from right to left and are indicated with even numbers starting from 0 (0, 2, 4, ..). The tunnel can become deadlocked if a left- bound and a right-bound car enter into the tunnel at the same time.

We want to prevent deadlock with two cars going different directions being in the tunnel at the same time.

I am using java 8 Mutex and semaphores. While I can prevent the deadlock I cannot get multiple cars going the same direction to be allowed to go before a car from the opposite direction can go. The cars take turns going instead which is not what the solution wants. I have also tried 2 Mutex locks one which locks the tunnel to one direction and one to allow a car to pass through.

```
    Q qp;
    LeftCar(Q qp) {
        this.qp = qp;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public synchronized void run() {
        int i = 0;
        int j;
        ArrayList<Integer> waiting = new ArrayList<>();


            while(i<30){
                if(qp.right_bound == 0){
                qp.produce(i);

                    try{
                        qp.lock.acquire();
                        try{
                            qp.enterL(i);
                            waiting.add(i);
                        }
                        finally{
                            while(waiting.size() > 0){
                                j = waiting.remove(0);
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                qp.exitL(j);
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("E");
                    }
                i += 2;
        }

qp.lock.release();
}
    }
}
```

This is pretty much the same for the RightCar as well. The only things in the Q class are pretty much print statements and the semaphores.

For example if there is a right-bound car already "in the tunnel" then any other right bound car should be allowed to go and they should exit in the order they go in.

Actual results:
Left Car: 10 wants to enter your secret tunnel
Right Car: 9 enters the secret tunal
Right Car: 9 exits the secret tunal
Right Car: 11 wants to enter your secret tunnel
Left Car: 10 enters the secret tunal
Left Car: 10 exits the secret tunal
Left Car: 12 wants to enter your secret tunnel
Right Car: 11 enters the secret tunal
Right Car: 11 exits the secret tunal
Right Car: 13 wants to enter your secret tunnel
Left Car: 12 enters the secret tunal
Left Car: 12 exits the secret tunal
Left Car: 14 wants to enter your secret tunnel
Right Car: 13 enters the secret tunal
Right Car: 13 exits the secret tunal
Right Car: 15 wants to enter your secret tunnel
Right Car: 15 enters the secret tunal
Right Car: 15 exits the secret tunal

Expected results:
Right-bound Car 1 wants to enter the tunnel.
Right-bound Car 1 is in the tunnel.
Right-bound Car 1 is exiting the tunnel.
Left-bound Car 4 wants to enter the tunnel.
Left-bound Car 4 is in the tunnel.
Left-bound Car 4 is exiting the tunnel.
Right-bound Car 5 wants to enter the tunnel.
Right-bound Car 5 is in the tunnel.
Left-bound Car 8 wants to enter the tunnel. 
Right-bound Car 5 is exiting the tunnel.
Left-bound Car 8 is in the tunnel. 
Right-bound Car 7 wants to enter the tunnel. 
Left-bound Car 10 wants to enter the tunnel.
Left-bound Car 8 is exiting the tunnel. 
Left-bound Car 10 is in the tunnel. 
Left-bound Car 12 wants to enter the tunnel.

Comment: I would create a simpler example program for your question, and simplify your question text.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking somebody to do your homework for you. Think about how this problem would be solved in real-life (i.e., real tunnel, real cars.) There would be a signalling system (traffic lights), and the system would have to progress through a set of states: Left-bound entrance is open, both entrances closed & waiting for left-bound traffic to exit, right-bound entrance is open, both entrances closed & waiting for right-bound traffic to exit....